# What's differant between Kali Linux versions

Tags: kali-linux

What's differant between Kali Linux versions? https://www.kali.org/downloads/
There's kali linx kde, xfce, light, light armhf, e17, mate, lxde. What's the difference?

Comment: Start at [the beginning](https://docs.kali.org/category/introduction). In there is a section about [Downloading Kali Linux](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/download-official-kali-linux-images), which describes the different versions available. However, **the most important part is [Should I use Kali Linux](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux)**.

Comment: ^^ I'd have made than an Answer but I missed the opportunity by about 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

What you are listing are desktop environments; the look and feel of you operating system' interface such as *kde* or *mate*. If it has *arm* in the name, then it is designed to run on the ARM chipset found in devices like the **raspberry pi**.